# javafx - how to create a loop of graphic components

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

In my javafx application I want to create a scene where I can show the usernames of all the users in my database.

Precisely, I want to show a list of labels where every label get a username.
(the number of labels depend on the number of users).

Note: I can do this in java with a list and a foreach loop, but this is the first time that I work with javafx and I want to know how to create a loop of graphic component.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a couple of alternatives, one sample is just looping and adding new labels to the children of a layout pane, the other is using the in-built ListView component.  There are other alternatives of course.  Which you choose to use will depend upon the functionality you need to achieve.

[image: screenshot]

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class UserDisplay extends Application {
    @Override public void start(Stage stage) {
        String[] users = { "Huey", "Dewey", "Louie" };

        VBox layout = new VBox(10);

        // ALTERNATIVE 1: add labels in a loop.
        for (String user: users) {
            Label userLabel = new Label(user);
            layout.getChildren().add(userLabel);
        }

        // ALTERNATIVE 2: use the built-in ListView component.
        ListView<String> listView = new ListView<>(
                FXCollections.observableArrayList(users)
        );
        layout.getChildren().add(listView);

        layout.setPadding(new Insets(10));
        layout.setPrefSize(100,200);

        stage.setScene(new Scene(layout));
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```